# Auto delete pages/posts without views

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-delete-post

Hello please does anyone know a way to automatically delete posts that doesn't get views within a period of time.
Lets say if a post on my site is made and within 30 days, there are no views on the post, is it possible to automatically place the post in draft or delete it

Comment: Are you already tracking views in any way?

Comment: I already have a page view plugin installed. This one https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-views-count/

Answer (score 0):

You could develop a plugin to track which URLs are getting requested, store that as a custom field for each post, and then run a cron job to delete the post_id that have post_views == 0 after a set period of time.

Comment: Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: You mean like waiting for someone else to develop it? I do not think this would be an easy plugin to develop. It is a lot easier to identify the content once every couple of months and delete it.